# Html Helpers Available in ASP.NET MVC controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to use the Html Helper class to build, for example, an Html.ActionLink from within a controller action.  I don't see it available from within controller actions.  What am I missing?

Comment: Oh, I totally understand to resist using Html Helpers in the controllers... but what happens when I want logic to control which link is presented?  Then I have to dump logic into my view.  Same violation, different area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using UrlHelper @ Controller.Url.  You can use it to generate a url, then pass it to your view.  The view is the right place to create a link to the url.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should be using the html helper methods in your controller. This stuff is best left in the view